# How to copy a complete php/mysql website with php?

Tags: php, html, caching, typo3

I have a typo3 website with no user genrated or dynamic content.
So it is unnecessary to use php and the database.

Is it possible (with php) to clone the hole website and store every page as an html page?
I have only a normal webspace, so i cant install tools like "eAccelerator".

My idea:
 - grab every link from the sitemap
 - file_get_contents -> store as html

But i think this is not a clean solution? Or?
Thanks in advance!
james

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple software called HTTRACK., here is the link:

[httrack.com](http://www.httrack.com/)

Comment: httrack will not copy php file or database

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use php to copy it? Did you consider using a command line tool like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)? wget allows you to create an "offline" copy of a website which you can of course host somewhere else. Sounds to me exactly like the thing you want to do.

In case you are really stucked to php, you will need an [HttpRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php), call the site, parse all links and resources, download the resources, follow the links and do the same again. This is the most simple solution, without any checking for conflicting resources or other stuff which could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sitesucker http://sitesucker.us is an excellent tool you can run from any mac. It works very well, I use it all the time.

But don't forget that by creating a static copy of your site, you will lose your templating functionality.  So if you really want to make your website static, I strongly recommend to - at least - put the identical parts of each page into php-includes. Mostly head, page header, footer, navigation. So you're ready for future changes.

If it's just because your TYPO3 is too slow, look at the nc_staticfilecache extension which can speed it up very well.

Answer (score 0):

Using TYPO3 where you need just a simple HTML is a **huge** overflow, invest in DreamWeaver and code all things 'manually'.